# Pass string to a linux cli interactive program with a script

Tags: linux, bash, telegram

I'm using a library for accessing telegram via command line in bash linux ubuntu.
It is telegram-cli.
REFERENCE https://github.com/vysheng/tg

It is an interactive program, which can be launched by

```
./bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub
```

It outputs these lines:

```
Telegram-cli version 1.1.1, Copyright (C) 2013-2014 Vitaly Valtman
Telegram-cli comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `show_license'.
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `show_license' for details.
I: config dir=[/home/utonto/.telegram-cli]
>
```

With the ">" prompt.
To send a msg, at this prompt you have to type

```
msg USERNAME This is a test message
```

I would like to make a script running on my pc, telling me the room temperature when i'm at work.
How can I do that?
I searched SO and found a similar question.
It was advised to use the "expect" command, I made so but it didn't work. Maybe -Surely- cos i'm a beginner.
I also tried

```
echo "msg USERNAME this is a message |
telegram-cli -k ......"
```

but it didn't work.
For your knowledge,on my android i have a telephone number which i use for telegram, but i registered to telegram-cli using another phone. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here: [remote control with Telegram](http://m.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-remote-control-with-Telegram/)

To intercept a new incoming message we create a file action.lua

> "Lua is a powerful, fast, lightweight, embeddable scripting language.
>
> Lua combines simple procedural syntax with powerful data description
>   constructs based on associative arrays and extensible semantics. Lua
>   is dynamically typed, runs by interpreting bytecode for a
>   register-based virtual machine, and has automatic memory management
>   with incremental garbage collection, making it ideal for
>   configuration, scripting, and rapid prototyping."

From http://www.lua.org.

```
sudo nano /home/pi/tg/action.lua
```

with this content

```
function on_msg_receive (msg)
    if msg.out then
        return
    end
    if (msg.text=='ping') then
        send_msg (msg.from.print_name, 'pong', ok_cb, false)
    end
end

function on_our_id (id)
end

function on_secret_chat_created (peer)
end

function on_user_update (user)
end

function on_chat_update (user)
end

function on_get_difference_end ()
end

function on_binlog_replay_end ()
end
```

Save and exit, when incoming text message is "ping", Telegram answers us with a text message containing "pong".

```
move in tg

cd /home/pi/tg
```

Then type

```
bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub -W -s action.lua
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a here document:

```
#!/bin/bash
./bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub <<-EOF
msg USERNAME This is a test message
exit
EOF
```

I added exit - do not know if it is needed.  NOTE: the EOF thing can be any bunch of letters that the shell cannot interpret as a command.  The - in front of the first EOF is there to tell the here doc that the next EOF is not in the leftmost column.  If you omit it, then the last EOF has to be as far left as you can go.  Column #1.

With regard to getting the temperature, I have no idea how you would do that without special hardware.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some way of getting the temperature to your computer, then to have bash send it to you is fairly trivial. The proper way to handle a recurring task is with `cron`. You would create a `crontab` entry launching your script (or directly sending the temperature itself to telegram). The format for a `cron entry` is:

```
* * * * * command_to_execute
| | | | |
| | | | +- day of week  (0-6) (Sunday = 0)
| | | +--- month        (1-12)
| | +----- day of month (1-31)
| +------- hour         (0-23)
+--------- minute       (0-59)
```

In your case you can set the `crontab` by using `crontab -e` (to edit your crontab entries). To send the temperature every 10 minues it would be:

```
*/10 * * * * ./script/to/call
```

or you could try invoking telegram directly in your `crontab` with something similar to:

```
*/10 * * * * echo "msg $USER The current temp is: $temperature" | ./bin/telegram-cli -k tg-server.pub
```

Lastly, check the options closely in `telegram-cli`, there may very well be one that takes a message as an argument and forwards it avoiding interactive mode altogether (I haven't checked).